# Horizontal ScrollVIew inside ListView not scrollling properly

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, horizontalscrollview

I just implemented HorizontalScrollView inside ListView.but list view not scrolling smoothly.
I want to show a list view and some of list item have a HorizontalScrollView.My HorizontalScroll Scrolls smoothly but Listview is not.

Below is my Code:

```
    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:divider="@color/LtGreen"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"

        android:smoothScrollbar="true"
        android:scrollingCache="false"
        android:animationCache="false"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

code of my getView method in adapter class is -

```
mHolder.mainLinearType1 = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.main_linear);
mHolder.hsv1 = (HorizontalScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.hsv);
```

code for load HorizontalScrollView for adapter item is -

```
    ScrollHandler mHandel = new ScrollHandler(mHolder.mainLinearType1, position);
    mHandel.loadLazyView();
```

and my Handler is -

```
public static class ScrollHandler extends Handler{

    LinearLayout mLayout;
    int mPosition;

    public ScrollHandler(LinearLayout linear,int pos){
        mLayout = linear;
        mPosition = pos;
    }

    public void loadLazyView(){
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mLayout.removeAllViews();
                for (int i = 0; i <mList.get(mPosition).getEventList().size(); i++) {
                    View additionView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_type1_subitem_view, null,false);
                    FrameLayout innerLinnerLayout=(FrameLayout)additionView.findViewById(R.id.frame_view);
                    mLayout.addView(innerLinnerLayout);
                }
            }
        };
        r.run();
    }
}
```

How can i make listview smooth.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you cannot do nested scroll in android, instead look into header or footer

Answer (score 0):

Check this :

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

I think this is what you need. Using an ASyncTask should make it smooth.

Answer (score 0):

Why is ScrollHandler extending Handler when it is not doing any handler specific work? The logic can be implemented in simple method say

```
loadLazyView (LinearLayout linear,int pos){...}
```

I think the list is slow because it is having complex hierarchy. Following link list 6 general ways to make your scrolling smoother. Kindly excuse if you have already seen this.

http://leftshift.io/6-ways-to-make-your-lists-scroll-faster-than-the-wind

The summary is

> 1. Reduce the number of conditions used in the getView of your adapter.
> 2. Check and reduce the number of garbage collection warnings that you get in the logs
> 3. If you're loading images while scrolling, get rid of them
> 4. Set scrollingCache and animateCache to false (more on this later)
> 5. Simplify the hierarchy of the list view row layout
> 6. Use the view holder pattern